# How read paths in text file and get the file count under that paths

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file which contains multiple paths like below

`$ cat directory.txt
/aaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/
/aaaa/bbbbb/eeeee/
/aaaa/bbbbb/ddddd/`

I need to change directory to each path in text file and need to get count of files under that paths.Below is the code i used, But it is not working.

`i=`cat /aaaa/bbbbb/directory.txt
`while read $i ;do
cd $i
ls |wc -l
done < /aaaa/bbbbb/count.txt`

Comment: can you provide your file content? your question is not very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're almost there. The line `i=...` is not needed, `read $i` should be `read i`, and you simply need to call `ls` with the path instead of `cd` it first.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i; do
ls "$i" | wc -l
done < "/xxx/yyy/count.txt"
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong, e.g. space in path. I update the answer.

Comment: i have updated my code please check i did any mistake ?? Still not working

Comment: @AnilKumarNelakuditi You edited in the wrong place :). You should edit the **question** instead of the **answer**.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat /nrt/home/directory.txt`;
do
cd $i
ls | wc -l
done >  /nrt/home/count.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one i tried this code it is working fine

## !/bin/bash

for i in `cat /nrt/home/directory.txt`;
`do
cd $i
ls | wc -l
done >  /nrt/home/count.txt`